# Else if in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to write else if statement in my Data weave but getting the error ***expression missing ""***

```
PBSI__Tax_Code__c                   : if((payload.order.customer."billing-address"."country-code" =="NL") "${sf_taxcode}" else if(payload.order.customer."billing-address"."country-code" =="DE") "${sf_deTaxcode}"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is missing the `else` of the last `if` sentence. [It is mandatory](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_if_else) to have an `else`.

As a simplified example:

```
{
    PBSI__Tax_Code__c: 
        if(country_code =="NL") "something" else if(country_code =="DE") "something" else "something else"
}
```

Also note that it in DataWeave configuration properties are accessed with the [p() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-mule-functions-p).

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    PBSI__Tax_Code__c : 
    if(payload.order.customer."billing-address"."country-code" =="NL") p('sf_taxcode') 
    else if(payload.order.customer."billing-address"."country-code" =="DE") p('sf_deTaxcode')
    else "as default"

}
```